# Is it necessary to apply security-related http headers to Rails asset files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, http-headers, assets

We're using https://github.com/twitter/secureheaders to apply security-related http headers to our Rails app. Recently, it's been suggested that it might be good to apply these same headers to our asset files as well. Is this necessary? AFAIK, our asset files reside in the same servers as our Rails apps, i.e they're not in some CDN.